# Show a full picture in a modal, from an array of pictures

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I need to open a full modal showing the picture that was clicked.
Here's my code so far:

**HTML main page**

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="insta in instagram" ng-if="$index % 3 == 0">
   <div class="col paddingPerfil colinstagram" ng-click="modal.show()" value="{{insta.valor}}" ng-repeat="insta in instagram.slice($index,
       ($index+3 > instagram.length ? instagram.length : $index+3))">
      <img src="{{insta.url}}" class="fotosInstagram">
   </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.instagram = [
   { valor: 1, url: 'img/teste/insta1.jpg' },
   { valor: 2, url: 'img/teste/insta2.jpg' },
   { valor: 3, url: 'img/teste/insta3.jpg' },
   { valor: 4, url: 'img/teste/insta4.jpg' },
   { valor: 5, url: 'img/teste/insta5.jpg' },
   { valor: 6, url: 'img/teste/insta6.jpg' },
   { valor: 7, url: 'img/teste/insta7.jpg' },
   { valor: 8, url: 'img/teste/insta8.jpg' },
   { valor: 9, url: 'img/teste/insta9.jpg' },

]
$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/modalPerfil.html', {
   scope: $scope
}).then(function(modal) {
   $scope.modal = modal;
});
```

**HTML Modal**

```
<div class="modalperfilimg">
   <img src="{{imgFull}}" style="width:100%;height:100%">
</div>
```

I can't find a simple solution for this.

Comment: If image size are not fixed so image might be not looking good so using below thing for display based on aspect ratio -> img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

Comment: The imgs have a fixed size, the class in them already do this, but this was not what I asked..